plpgsql function with "case when" to update column value
I want to create a plpgsql function that will be called by a BEFORE INSERT trigger.
This function is updating a column based on value from another column.
Here is the code:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Xupd_cat_prop()
                           RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$ 
DECLARE categ_prop varchar;
BEGIN
    kateg_prop := CASE
        WHEN new.cat_tarif = 'domestic_1' OR new.cat_tarif = 'domestic_2' THEN new.class = 'DOM'
        WHEN new.cat_tarif = 'nondomestic_1' THEN new.class = 'NONDOM'
        WHEN new.cat_tarif = 'industry' THEN new.class = 'IND'
    END;
  RETURN new; 
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

But this doesn't work. I am using Postgres 16.
The error is somewhere with the WHEN clause.

You use SQL CASE statement. The WHEN clause can contains only expressions:
kateg_prop := CASE
        WHEN new.cat_tarif = 'domestic_1' OR new.cat_tarif = 'domestic_2' THEN 'DOM'
        WHEN new.cat_tarif = 'nondomestic_1' THEN 'NONDOM'
        WHEN new.cat_tarif = 'industry' THEN 'IND'
    END;

Although the syntax is similar, there are significant differences between SQL (functional) and PL/pgSQL (procedural) CASE:
SQL CASE:
 CASE var WHEN expr THEN expr [...] END

PLpgSQL CASE
  CASE var WHEN expr THEN plpgsql statement [...] END CASE

SQL CASE returns a value, PL/pgSQL CASE executes statements.
